# phonegap geocoder.geocode get the house number from results

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, google-maps

I have this geocoder code:

```
function codeLatLng(lat, lng) {
 geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      console.log(results)
        if (results[1]) {
         //formatted address
         alert(results[0].formatted_address)//this is a string of all location 

        } else {
          alert("No results found");
        }
      } else {
        alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
```

I want to save  the street and house number in a  different variables, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro), instead of getting the `formatted_address` you can get the `address_components` from the Geocoding API response, and then get for example the `street_number`:

```
"address_components" : [
    {
       "long_name" : "1600",
       "short_name" : "1600",
       "types" : [ "street_number" ]
    },
    ...
]
```

You can get the desired components iterating over the `address_components` (I'm retrieving `street_number` in this example):

```
for (var i = 0; i < results[0].address_components.length; i++) {
    var address_components = results[0].address_components[i];
    if (address_components.types[0] == 'street_number') {
        console.log(address_components.long_name);
    }
}
```